# DBT ERROR : Model 'a depends on a node named 'b' which is disabled

Tags: compilation, dbt

Model b is being referenced on model a

Model b is active and I have checked for the naming conventions as well in the model a reference

It is same as the sql file name

could you please help me resolve this

Comment: can you share your code? it is difficult for us to help you debug with no more hints

Comment: Have you checked the `yml` file for model b, the config section for model b, and also check to see if model b is not in a directory that's disabled

Answer (score 0):

First check that Model b, in the project.yml file, or the corresponding .yml file,  is not set to +enable=false. If it is, set it to +enable=true.

If the corresponding .yml file with the relevant table/model does not specify whether enabled is set to True or False,then open the model b file, and search for a configuration within model b which sets +enable=false and set to +enable=true.

It will look something like this:

```
{{ config(
  enabled=true | false
) }}

select ...
```